# I'm using interrupts to detect button press lengths, but it will sometimes not detect that I've released the button

Tags: arduino, interrupt

```
#include <DS3231.h>

DS3231 clock;
RTCDateTime dt;

const int INTERRUPT_PIN = 2;
int prevTime, pressedTime, releasedTime, heldTime;
bool settingTimes = false;
int startHour1, startMin1, startHour2, startMin2, endHour1, endMin1, endHour2 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initialize DS3231
  clock.begin();
  clock.setDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);

  pinMode(INTERRUPT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN), actButtonPress, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  if (!settingTimes) {
    dt = clock.getDateTime();

    // For leading zero look to DS3231_dateformat example
    Serial.print(dt.hour);   Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(dt.minute);

    delay(1000); 
  } else {
    //Serial.println("Setting Times, Check the buttons");  
  }
}

void actButtonPress() {
  if (prevTime + 100 < millis()) {
    Serial.println("This is being called");
    if (digitalRead(INTERRUPT_PIN) == LOW) { //Button has been pressed
      pressedTime = millis();
    } else {
      releasedTime = millis();
      heldTime = releasedTime - pressedTime;

      if (heldTime > 3000) {
        settingTimes = !settingTimes;  
      } else {
        Serial.println("Change Page");  
      }
    }
    prevTime = millis();  
  }
}
```

I want to be able to press the button for 3 seconds to set times, and anything less times, I want to change pages. I need to use interrupts because the ds3231 get date time function doesn't seem to work without the delay statement (I've already tried the millis() function)

Comment: use the Bounce2 library

Comment: Interrupts are disabled while you are in actButtonPress.  Removing the lengthy Serial.print statements f'om your interrupt routiine will help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using interrupts is generally not a good idea for checking button presses.  Switch inputs should always be considered as rather dirty signals... The initial contact is never clean-cut, there is always some noise before the signal is clean.  That's called "bounce".

To debounce your switch input you should either:

- wait a little while using a counter, or a time stamp, (using millis) before checking if the button is released.
- or only poll the switches at regular intervals.

The duration of the bounce depends on the switch, and will degrade over time as the switch gets older.  In practice, 30 ms is a good value for the delay.

I suggest you try this:

```
#include <DS3231.h>

DS3231 clock;
RTCDateTime dt;

// putting all switch states in this struct to take advantage of bit-sized
// storage, and save RAM space for the rest of the program.
struct SwitchStates
{
    unsigned char action : 1;   // state of action switch.
    unsigned char sw1    : 1;   // add one bit for each switch you have. 
};

// you need to keep track of previous switch states to detect changes.
SwitchStates previousSwitchState; 

#define ACTION_SWITCH_PIN     (2)
#define SWITCH_TIME_SET_DELAY (3000)  // time to hold switch for setting time in ms.
#define SWITCH_POLLING_DELAY  (30)    // switch polling delay, in ms.    
#define RTC_READ_DELAY        (1000)  // RTC read delay in ms.

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Initialize DS3231
    clock.begin();
    clock.setDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);    // imho, that's not a very good idea...  

    pinMode(ACTION_SWITCH_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
    digitalWrite(ACTION_SWITCH_PIN, HIGH);    // you must set the pin high 
                                              // for pull-up to work. 
}


// only used witin loop()
static unsigned char switchPollingTimeStamp = 0;  // char because 30 is less than 256.
static bool settingTimes = false;
static unsigned int rtcReadTimeStamp = 0;
static unsigned int modeSwitchTimeStamp = 0;

void loop() 
{
    // get current timestamp.
    unsigned long now = millis(); 

    if ((unsigned char)now - switchPollingTimeStamp >= SWITCH_POLLING_DELAY)
    {
        switchPollingTimeStamp = (unsigned char)now;

        // all switch inputs will be handled within this block.
        SwitchStates curSwitchState;       

        // polling at regular intervals, first read your inputs.
        curSwitchState.action = digitalRead(ACTION_SWITCH_PIN);

        // curSwitchState.sw1 = digitalRead(SW1_PIN);
        // etc...

        // check activity on action (mode) switch and do timing, etc... 
        if (curSwitchState.action && !previousSwitchState.action)
        {
            // keep track of how long the switch has been held
            modeSwitchTimeStamp = (unsigned int)now;    
            if (settingTimes)
                settingTimes = false;  // exit time set mode, for example.
            else
                Serial.pritln("Next Page");  // 
        }
        else if (curSwitchState.action)
        {
            // after 3000 ms, switch to timeset mode.
            if ((unsigned int)now - modeSwitchTimeStamp >= SWITCH_TIME_SET_DELAY)
            {
                if (!settingTimes)
                {
                    settingTimes = true:
                    Serial.println("Entering time set mode"); 
                }
            }
        }

        // That was the most complex one, others should be easier
        if (settingTimes)
        {
             if (curState.sw1 && !previousSwitchState.sw1)
             {
                 // whatever this switch would do in set time state. 
             }
             // etc...
        } 
        else
        {
            // the same when not in set time state.
        }

        // to keep track of switch activity. 
        // by first storing current switch states, then saving them
        // like this, you cannot forget one, this avoids any 'I missed one' bugs.            
        previousSwitchState = curSwitchState;
    }

    // try to keep your code non blocking, so your device stays responsive...
    // in other words, avoid calling delay().
    if (!settingTimes && (unsigned int)now - rtcReadTimeStamp >= RTC_READ_DELAY) 
    {
        rtcReadTimeStamp - (unsigned int)millis();
        dt = clock.getDateTime();
        // For leading zero look to DS3231_dateformat example
        Serial.print(dt.hour);   Serial.print(":");
        Serial.println(dt.minute);
    } 
}
```

Note: I don't have an arduino with me, and the laptop I have is not set up for it, so I coud not compile and debug it.  It should be very close, though.